# How to generate posterior predictive samples with size different than the observed variable in pymc3?

Tags: bayesian, python, posterior, pymc

I have a simple probabilistic model with Beta prior and Bernoulli likelihood:

```
with pm.Model() as model:
  mu = pm.Beta('mu', alpha=2.0, beta=2.0)
  x = pm.Bernoulli('x', p=mu, observed=x_obs)

  trace = pm.sample(1000)
```

my observed value `x_obs` is of shape `(8,)`, so when I sample from `sample_posterior_predictive()`, I always get samples with the same size:

```
samples = pm.sample_posterior_predictive(trace, samples=10000, model=model)
samples['x'].shape
>>> (10000, 8)
```

How can I sample n different Bernoulli draws other than 8? For example with shape= (10000, n)?

Comment: I would have thought that `8` refers to dimensionality, rather than number of samples, which in your case is `n = 10000`?

Comment: @microhaus The observed values are simply a set containing 8 consecutive coin tosses result (bunch of ones and zeros), and yes the 10,000 is the number of samples from the posterior predictive.

Comment: For anyone coming here in the future: You should be able to achieve this using the `size` parameter. E.g. `pm.sample_posterior_predictive(trace, samples=10000, model=mode, size=100)` would generate simulated data with a shape of `(10000,100,8)`